# Does this equation always spit out a natural number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was messing around with WolframAlpha when I found that, apparently,
$$\frac{(10^n-1)}{s}$$
is a natural number for some natural number *n* and any odd *s* not divisible by 5. For example,
For *s* = 137, *n* = 8
For *s* = 29, *n* = 28
For *s* = 61, *n* = 60
For *s* = 49, *n* = 42
etc.
Curiously, should *s* be prime, $$n=s-1$$
It holds true for *s* = 3, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 61, 137, 2017, 9887.
I've taken a crack at proving/ disproving this to no avail. Could anyone here enlighten me?

Comment: To clarify, your claim is that $p\mid 10^{p-1}-1$ for each prime $p$ not equal to $2$ or $5$?  Have you ever heard of [fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)?  Or is your claim that for every odd $s$ which is not a multiple of $5$ there exists some $n$ such that $s\mid 10^n-1$?

Comment: For the first, it follows immediately from fermat's little.  For the second, consider using induction both on the number of distinct primes, and the multiplicity of each prime, with fermat's little in conjunction with chinese remainder.